# How do I move a control in Vaadin designer without changing which component it is a child of?

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to use the latest Vaadin Designer (v8) to layout a bunch of controls in an absolute layout.  I also have a horizontal layout that is on the same layout.

My problem is I just want to move a label to an absolute x,y position within absolute layout.  I know I can achieve this by hand or by nudging the label to the x,y I want with the arrow keys.  When I try to drag it onto the layout however this happens.

Perhaps there is no way to do this.  I was thinking there should be a feature like holding down alt-key while dragging keeps the control within its current layout?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right. You can achieve it by using arrow key or `Position` property (if you are in an AbsoluteLayout) but currently, there is no way to do that by dragging the components.

Whenever you drag some components over a layout, it will be always hooked into that layout.

Your suggestion about using ALT-key to avoid this problem is very nice. The team would very much appreciate if you can fill in an issue (https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/new) as a feature request/improvement which we can consider later on.